# Not achieve expected outcomes while using cut function for pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use the cut function to classified my data into 4 different classes.  There is no syntax error in my code. But the outcome is not what I expected.

MACOS 10.14.1,python3

coor.x and coor.y are columns which I want to classified and labeled using the cut function:

```
coor['xarea']=pd.cut(coor.x,[144.7,144.85,145,145.15,145.3,145.45],include_lowest=True,labels={'1','2','3','4','5'})

coor['yarea']=pd.cut(coor.y,[-38.1,-37.95,-37.8,-37.65,-37.5],include_lowest=True,labels={'1','2','3','4'})
```

The expected result is :

```
     x         y     xarea yarea
144.994667  -37.924948  2   2
144.987191  -37.924919  2   2
144.986557  -37.924911  2   2
144.987280  -37.924902  2   2
```

But the real outcome is :

```
   x            y    xarea yarea
144.994667  -37.924948  2   3
144.987191  -37.924919  2   3
144.986557  -37.924911  2   3
144.987280  -37.924902  2   3
```

I do not understand why data in y got the wrong labels, cause when I run the code without labels attribute, I got this:

```
144.987191  -37.924919  2   (-37.95, -37.8]
144.986557  -37.924911  2   (-37.95, -37.8]
144.987280  -37.924902  2   (-37.95, -37.8]
```

which means it has been well classified.

Comment: change `labels` to a list: labels={'1','2','3','4'} --> labels=['1','2','3','4']. with a `set`, the order of the values in labels is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, I get the following:

```
coor['xarea']=pd.cut(coor.x,[144.7,144.85,145,145.15,145.3,145.45],include_lowest=True,labels={'1','2','3','4','5'})
coor['yarea']=pd.cut(coor.y,[-38.1,-37.95,-37.8,-37.65,-37.5],include_lowest=True,labels={'1','2','3','4'})
print(coor)
```

```
            x          y xarea yarea
0  144.994667 -37.924948     2     2
1  144.987191 -37.924919     2     2
2  144.986557 -37.924911     2     2
3  144.987280 -37.924902     2     2
```

It is working correctly for me.

Comment: It seems I should use square bracket rather than curly bracket for the label list. Anyway, thanks for your help!